# Open source Android libraries? Reusable Views, ViewGroups, Adapters etc?

Tags: open-source, android-widget, android, library-project

Here's what I really want: a site collecting re-usable components for Android.

I have found various [small](http://androidcontrols.org/controls) [lists](http://android-libraries.com/), the biggest being the [Open Intents](http://www.openintents.org/en/libraries) library list. Mark Murphy (hi, Mark) also lists the library projects he publishes.

None of this is of the same order as, say [Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/controls?sort=rating) or [Cocoa Objects](http://cocoaobjects.com).

Where do you go to grab re-usable libraries for Android?

**Edit**: this isn't just about library projects, though this would be ideal. On the flip side: where do I publish my open-sourced library projects, over and above just "Github".

Comment: "Here's what I really want: a site collecting re-usable components for Android." -- I have been begging for people to make one for years.

Comment: First link is broken.

Comment: I find these kinds of questions very helpful, and it annoys the crap out of me that SO keeps trying to shut them down.  There is clearly demand for this kind of information, so they should either relax their policies or find a better way to support this kind of question.

Comment: http://android-arsenal.com

Comment: [android-libs.com](https://www.android-libs.com)

Comment: @greg7gkb I believe that is why we started a software recommendation SE site.

Comment: Hey deer, I am using this application: [Libraries for developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=tr) maybe you can check it out !

Comment: You can also give a look at https://android.libhunt.com . It is the most useful website to help you find android libs. Cheers!

Answer (score 40):

*Update June 28, 2013: More libraries*

Some high quality ones:

- [actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com)
- [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview)
- [FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar)
- [Square Open Source Android libraries](http://square.github.io/#android) (multiple high quality libraries)
- [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)
- [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
- [FunDapter](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter)
- [viewpagerindicator.com](http://viewpagerindicator.com)
- [GreenDroid](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/) or the <s>[GDCatalog demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog)</s>

See also:

- [Android UI Patterns](https://plus.google.com/108176685096570584154/posts/FMGdzuMY2nZ) App demoing and listing *lots* of components from various developers (the app has been removed from the playstore, the link to it points to the developers post in google plus to the binaries and extra info)
- [Android Views](http://www.androidviews.net/)
- [Android Weekly's Toolbox page](http://androidweekly.net/toolbox)
- [Androidplot](http://androidplot.com) for charts etc
- [**Android-Arsenal**](http://android-arsenal.com) great collection for all kinds of libraries

Related:

- [android-resources-each-developer-should-know](http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/android-resources-each-developer-should-know/)

Comment: Android UI Patterns is a good start, thanks.

Comment: controlsandroid.com is trying to collect all the UI and control libraries as well, give them a try

Answer (score 15):

You may want to take a look at [Android Views](http://www.androidviews.net/).

It is pretty new but it provides useful links to re-usable components for Android.

It also has a simple rating and commenting system.

Comment: Very organised, and has almost every cool feature you may want to implement. Thanks!

Comment: Android Views went offline however if you know a subdirectory the content is still online. E.g. http://www.androidviews.net/category/libraries/

Answer (score 8):

This site is a great reference for collecting libraries for Android as well as other mobile app platforms:

http://appdevwiki.com/wiki/show/HomePage

Answer (score 3):

These site have a great collection of android open source libraries, just in case you are interested:

http://android-arsenal.com/

https://f-droid.org/

You can also download these apps for checking out different libraries :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tual

Comment: http://www.theultimateandroidlibrary.com/ not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

[Scott Alexander Brown](https://twitter.com/scottyab) has an [excellent talk](http://www.alexander-bown.com/2012/11/write-less-do-more-droidcon-2012/) covering some very useful tools.

He also points out The Ultimate Android Library (TUAL), which is analogous to Cocoa Controls.

**Edit:**
The site [DroidStyle](http://droidstyle.aaplab.com) gives a series of examples of UI Patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful libraries:

I want to suggest you few android libraries, that is pretty well made (I think):

[AndroidSideMenu](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu) - lets you create slide menu (like in YouTube app). I know that there is a bunch of alternatives, but this one is much faster. Overdraw is reduced and main layout is cached while drawing, so it perfect solution if your layout is "heavy". No tricks with HorizontalScrollView - this one uses pure android-way to create view.

[CircleLayout](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout) - lets you arrange views into a circle (views just arranged in circle) or pie (views are cropped to form a nice looking pie).

Answer (score 0):

I commit on OAK Android Kit: http://willowtreeapps.github.com/OAK/

It also includes a quick-start to get an android app up and running in very short order:

http://willowtreeapps.github.com/OAK/quick-start.html